# visual studio c# chart with only one axis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

I'm trying to create in c# in Visual studio a nice way to show the minimum, maximum and actual value of a "variable" (Variable is a class). I was trying to use the charts to do that but I have two problems.
1) It shows in 2D and I only need 1 dimension.
2) I can't write tags on the values, in this case to show which is the minimum, the maximum and the current value.
Is there a SeriesChartType that does that?
I would appreciate ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much the chart type but the various styling options you need to play with.

Here is an example using `ChartType.Point`:

[image]

```
// no legend:
chart.Legends.Clear();

// a couple of short references:
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart.Series[0];

// no y-axis:            
ca.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
ca.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
ca.AxisY.Maximum = 1;

// use your own values:
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
ca.AxisX.Maximum = 100;

// style the ticks, use your own values:
ca.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Size = 7;
ca.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 10;
ca.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
ca.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Size = 3;
ca.AxisX.MinorTickMark.Interval = 2;

// I turn the axis labels off.
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
// If you want to show them pick a reasonable Interval!
ca.AxisX.Interval = 1;

// no gridlines
ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

// the most logical type
// note that you can change colors, sizes, shaps and markerstyles..
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

// display x-value above; make sure you have enough room!
S1.Label = "#VALX";

// a few test data:
S1.Points.AddXY(1, 0.1);
S1.Points.AddXY(11, 0.1);
S1.Points.AddXY(17, 0.1);
S1.Points.AddXY(81, 0.1);
```

Note that you can play with the `Series.SmartLabelStyle` to display values when they are too dense!

I add the `DataPoints` at an y-value of `0.1`. You can change it to move the points up or down a little..